# Replacing preserve-3d using jquery for use with IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, 3d, transform

So, I've got this simple cardflip using jquery on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4v5enfp

```
$(".flip").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
    return false;
});
```

It works on all browsers I have tried (or at least would work with some webkittery), except, you guessed it, IE.

I was thinking since preserve-3d is supposed to pass on the 3d transforms to the child elements, I could just fiddle around with the jquery to get it working. So I made this silly thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/7x0es3pa/2

```
card = $(".card");
$(".flip").hover(function () {
    flip(card);
    return false;
});

function flip(el) {
    children = el.children();
    el.toggleClass('flipped');
    //if IE
    children.toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

Imagine "if" there works (so tested on IE/doesn't have to work on other browsers).

My understanding of the workings of 3d transforms and preserve-3d is probably at fault here, but I'm out of ideas. Preferably this should work without changing the CSS.

First question, I hope I didn't mess up too much. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is this supposed to flip on mouse hover? If so, it's not working on any browser

Comment: I've removed all the webkits to make it easier to view, and then tested on chrome and it worked. Here's the original: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/. I've tested on chrome, but should work on FF.

Comment: IE now supports preserve-3d in the Windows 10 tech preview. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx